# How to add "Copy Location" Constraint programmatically?

Tags: python, constraints

Let's say I have 2 objects: 1 empty and 1 cube. How could I create a "Copy Location" constraint for the empty, so it follows the cube's movement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
obj = scene.objects['Cube']
empty = scene.objects['Empty']

constraint = obj.constraints.new('COPY_LOCATION')
constraint.target = empty
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding operators. This function-based approach is faster and more reliable.